# How to make width of columns in table smaller

Tags: tables

So I basically create all my tables in Excel and then transfer to Texnic Center by using the Excel2LaTeX addin for Excel. I am not too familiar with adjusting the outputted code to my own likings. For example, I have the following table (directly from Excel2LaTeX):

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
  \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
    \toprule
    Dependent variable: & $CoJPoD_{system|sov}$ &       & $\Delta$$CoJPoD_{system|sov}$ &       & $CoJPoD_{sov|system}$ &  \\
    \midrule
          &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & \textbf{(1)}   & \textbf{(2)}   & \textbf{(3)}   & \textbf{(4)}   & \textbf{(5)}   & \textbf{(6)} \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    Constant & -11.116*** & -10.045*** & -6.668*** & -5.597*** & 13.194*** & 13.938*** \\
          & (-2.934) & (-3.540) & (-2.939) & (-3.000) & (3.584) & (3.556) \\
    Market Ret (6 months) (\%) & 0.001*** &       & 0.001*** &       & 0.000 &  \\
          & (3.022) &       & (3.645) &       & (-0.016) &  \\
    Market Vol (6 months) (\%) & 0.008 &       & 0.009 &       & 0.008 &  \\
          & (0.686) &       & (1.127) &       & (0.458) &  \\
    Market Ret (1 month) (\%) &       & 0.013** &       & 0.010** &       & -0.021*** \\
          &       & (2.010) &       & (2.171) &       & (-2.723) \\
    Market Vol (1 month) (\%) &       & -1.949*** &       & -1.629*** &       & -0.051 \\
          &       & (-4.682) &       & (-5.221) &       & (-0.063) \\
    Log GDP & 0.913*** & 0.826*** & 0.550*** & 0.463*** & -1.180*** & -1.242*** \\
          & (2.882) & (3.470) & (2.919) & (2.943) & (-3.824) & (-3.764) \\
    Debt/GDP (\%) & 0.004*** & 0.004*** & 0.002* & 0.002 & 0.004* & 0.004* \\
          & (2.796) & (2.825) & (1.953) & (1.949) & (1.750) & (1.730) \\
    Reserve/Debt (\%) & 0.0689** & 0.071** & 0.043** & 0.045* & 0.075** & 0.072** \\
          & (2.478) & (2.322) & (2.101) & (1.919) & (2.371) & (2.325) \\
    Term Spread (\%) & 0.0423*** & 0.041*** & 0.038*** & 0.037*** & 0.012 & 0.015** \\
          & (6.244) & (6.984) & (7.033) & (7.261) & (1.312) & (2.154) \\
    VSTOXX (\%) & 0.004*** & 0.003*** & 0.003*** & 0.002*** & 0.008*** & 0.007868*** \\
          & (4.853) & (4.192) & (4.389) & (3.737) & (7.545) & (7.848) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    Bank fixed effects & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes \\
    No. of observations & 620   & 620   & 620   & 620   & 620   & 620 \\
    Adjusted $R^2$ & 0.728 & 0.719 & 0.774 & 0.760 & 0.822 & 0.822 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:addlabel}
\end{table}
```

Basically, the table is too wide to fit onto a portrait page (I do not want to use landscape). I see that there is quite a wide gap between each column, is there a way for me to reduce the gap between columns?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `p{1.5cm}` instead of `c`. Adjust the width as per your requirement. You can also tune gap between two columns if required.

```
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm} p{2cm}p{2cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}}
```

Your Table

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
  \begin{tabular}{p{2cm} p{2cm}p{2cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}}

    Dependent variable: & $CoJPoD_{system|sov}$ &       & $\Delta$$CoJPoD_{system|sov}$ &       & $CoJPoD_{sov|system}$ &  \\

          &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & \textbf{(1)}   & \textbf{(2)}   & \textbf{(3)}   & \textbf{(4)}   & \textbf{(5)}   & \textbf{(6)} \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    Constant & -11.116*** & -10.045*** & -6.668*** & -5.597*** & 13.194*** & 13.938*** \\
          & (-2.934) & (-3.540) & (-2.939) & (-3.000) & (3.584) & (3.556) \\
    Market Ret (6 months) (\%) & 0.001*** &       & 0.001*** &       & 0.000 &  \\
          & (3.022) &       & (3.645) &       & (-0.016) &  \\
    Market Vol (6 months) (\%) & 0.008 &       & 0.009 &       & 0.008 &  \\
          & (0.686) &       & (1.127) &       & (0.458) &  \\
    Market Ret (1 month) (\%) &       & 0.013** &       & 0.010** &       & -0.021*** \\
          &       & (2.010) &       & (2.171) &       & (-2.723) \\
    Market Vol (1 month) (\%) &       & -1.949*** &       & -1.629*** &       & -0.051 \\
          &       & (-4.682) &       & (-5.221) &       & (-0.063) \\
    Log GDP & 0.913*** & 0.826*** & 0.550*** & 0.463*** & -1.180*** & -1.242*** \\
          & (2.882) & (3.470) & (2.919) & (2.943) & (-3.824) & (-3.764) \\
    Debt/GDP (\%) & 0.004*** & 0.004*** & 0.002* & 0.002 & 0.004* & 0.004* \\
          & (2.796) & (2.825) & (1.953) & (1.949) & (1.750) & (1.730) \\
    Reserve/Debt (\%) & 0.0689** & 0.071** & 0.043** & 0.045* & 0.075** & 0.072** \\
          & (2.478) & (2.322) & (2.101) & (1.919) & (2.371) & (2.325) \\
    Term Spread (\%) & 0.0423*** & 0.041*** & 0.038*** & 0.037*** & 0.012 & 0.015** \\
          & (6.244) & (6.984) & (7.033) & (7.261) & (1.312) & (2.154) \\
    VSTOXX (\%) & 0.004*** & 0.003*** & 0.003*** & 0.002*** & 0.008*** & 0.007868*** \\
          & (4.853) & (4.192) & (4.389) & (3.737) & (7.545) & (7.848) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    Bank fixed effects & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes \\
    No. of observations & 620   & 620   & 620   & 620   & 620   & 620 \\
    Adjusted $R^2$ & 0.728 & 0.719 & 0.774 & 0.760 & 0.822 & 0.822 \\
    \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:addlabel}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does adjust the width but also makes all my columns left justified. Is there a way to adjust the width but still centre justify?

Comment: I also want to know about the last comment :-)

Answer (score 1):

For guys looking for center align while shrinking margins, add:

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{C{1cm}C{1cm}}
test for this & test for this
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```